# how to display only button with out jframe or jpanel visible?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Example below will display a button with jframe window. I want only button visible, how can it be implement?

```
public final void initUI() {

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  getContentPane().add(panel);

  panel.setLayout(null);

  JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
   quitButton.setBounds(50, 60, 80, 30);
   quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
           System.exit(0);
      }
   });

   panel.add(quitButton);

   setTitle("Quit button");
   setSize(300, 200);
   setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: No Frame -> No Button

Comment: +1 oh..then what is common practice people do to display button on image (splash screen , .jpg etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by *"with out jframe or jpanel visible?"* you create a transparent window...

[image: Boo]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GhostButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GhostButton();
    }

    public GhostButton() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JButton ghostButton = new JButton("Boo!");
                ghostButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(ghostButton);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

If you remove `frame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));`, you will get a frameless window

ps- This works under Java 7+, there is trick to make it work under Java 6, but I've not posted it here

Comment: Yup I support this answer. In few minute ill rate your answer